# Using If statement with Index Match to look through workbooks when cell is blank

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a workbook with multiple sheets which I am trying to collate specific bits of data onto one.  The following formula is working when I look at the first sheet ("Matched Funding"):

```excel
=INDEX('Matched Funding'!$A$2:$Q$100,0,MATCH("Date",'Matched Funding'!$1:$1,0),1)
```

I would like that once the formula hits the end of the list (i.e. a blank cell) that it looks to the next sheet ("Together") for the same information (i.e. look for "date" in the next sheet) and so on.

I've attached the 2 worksheets below.  As you can see, the column have different headings hence my need for Index Match.

[image: "Matched Funding"]
[image: "Together"]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use iferror() so if the first index/match fails it goes to the second like this:

=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(A1,A2:A5,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(A7:A10,MATCH(A1,A7:A10,0)),"No Match"))

[image]

You could extend that, but I would consider consolidating the data myself...

Comment: If there is no result for the match then index/match will give an error - which is how we get to the second. have you built this to see? tyr it and change the 6 in cell B2 to 2 then 11...

Comment: How would you consolidate the data?  I built your example but it's not working when I apply it to my data.

Comment: Well, I cannot see what you put - I know my example works, did you make an error defining a range?. You should know your data so you should be able to see how you could make one dataset out of two...